# Delete a SMS Conversation

Tags: android, database, cursor, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

Trying to Delete the whole Conversation by using the Number, like this :

```
 mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),"address="+Number, null);
```

But Nothing Happen,No Force Close & its not Deleted, any Help ?,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do it in two steps. something like this:

**A.**  Query SMS database by address to obtain your SMS's message id:

```
 String numberFilter = "address='"+ phoneNumber + "'";
 String messageid = null;
 Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), 
              null, numberFilter, null, null);

 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      messageid = cursor.getString(0);
 }
```

**B.**  Delete SMS using message id:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + messageid), null, null);
```

Now, for multiple deletions. You reported multi-deletion failed when you
use cursor iteration (`while cursor.moveToFirst()`). I never tried it but I assume

It has something to do with cursor invalidated after delete. Try instead to restart the cursor before each delete, something like this:

```
 for (;;) {
     // restart cursor before each delete
     String messageid = null;
     Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), 
                  null, numberFilter, null, null);

     if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       break; // nothing more to delete
     }

     // delete single record
     messageid = cursor.getString(0);
     getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + messageid), null, null);
 }
```

You will need write SMS permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```